# 1997 dodge caravan won't start when motor gets hot

Tags: electrical, starting, dodge, caravan

I have a van with the 3.3 in it. It will start in the morning to go to work sometimes die on the way and restart. It also will not start when the motor gets hot it will turn over but not getting any spark. Leave it sit for a few hours and it will start back up. I changed the coil, spark plugs and wires, and the cam shaft sensor. Don't Know what else to do please help!

Answer (score 2):

I would check the fuel pump actually. It might be getting too hot, causing it to not put out the proper pressure. The only way to test this (that I'm aware of) is while it's running. You'd have to put a pressure gauge on it (at the rail) and check the fuel pressure while running. You'd then need to leave the gauge in place, somewhere you can see it while driving. People I have talked to have somehow taped it near the windshield so it can be seen with the hood closed. Looks stupid, but gets the job done.

**NOTE:** You do not want to have the gauge in the passenger compartment with you just in case it were to spring a leak for some reason, you'd have gasoline all over the inside of your vehicle as well as the possibility of a fireball ... not fun.

When you engine quits, you'd need to ensure you can see what the gauge is doing. If the pressure slowly lowers to much lower than what it is when the engine is running normally, this could be your issue.

Comment: So if there is not enough fuel pressure this would also cause my coil to not work?

Comment: @user6985 ... You said "it's not getting any spark" ... Are you actually saying it isn't getting spark or it isn't running? How are you verifying no spark if that is indeed what you are saying.

Comment: Yes it is not getting any spark. The times when it won't start you can turn the motor over and take the spark plug wires off and there is no juice going to the coil.

Comment: It is not getting spark it will turn over and you can hear the pump kicking  on.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong ... Totally misunderstood. Is there no juice going to the coil, or coming from the coil? "Going to" would mean to me the 12v connection is dead. "Coming from" would mean you are not getting spark to the spark plugs.

Comment: No juice coming from the coil. And when it dies going down the road I put it in neutral with out stopping the car and turn the key. It takes about three times of turning the key and it will start back up. Put it back in drive and down the road I go.

Comment: Would the crank sensor cause this?

Comment: The intermittent nature of the issue is what's bothering me. Usually when the crank position sensor goes dead, it stays dead. Same with a cam sensor. I don't like the practice of Remove & Replace mechanicing. It just costs way too much and takes too much time. I don't know the procedure for testing your crank sensor either, so am deign to make the suggestion. It is conceivable, though.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also had people at work tell me to change my key switch. But I don't have the money to put all this in and it not work. But on the other hand I did only give 400 dollars for the van.

Comment: I would put the ignition switch way down on your list of things to replace. When it goes bad it's a whole different set of problems you aren't seeing here.

Comment: I will keep you posted on the things that I do and if it works. Thanks again for help.

Comment: Everybody takes the "BATTERY"  for granted.  The battery is used everyday for about 5-8 years and 9 out of 10 times  people will think BATTERY but then they begin to look at motor instead

Answer (score 0):

Everybody takes the "BATTERY"  for granted.  The battery is used everyday for about 5-8 years and people would like to believe that the problem could never their battery!.  No Power?   Check the battery first before installing new parts.  Get a used but GOOD battery and switch the batteries.  Try to start the car.  If it starts then do this several more times.  If it starts 10 times in a row then I guess you know what your problem was, if not then you will need to do a diagnostic on the vehicle.  check out the following video to learn "How To Do A No Start-No Crank Diagnosis on your car. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WwdBEENa7Is If you are not going to do the work yourself then at least watch it to educate yourself before speaking with the mechanic.  Don't be fooled!  If you sound like you know what you're talking about the mechanic will be fooled and not you.